# How can I see and storage the data from device in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-communication, qtserialport

[image]

my ui with qt .

[image]

**what I want.**

I am in serial communication qt with my device. I make a ui and I can connect my device using ui. I want get a data log from device and display in qt using QTimer.

how can I do it ? and also want save data to csv file.

please help me and let me know how can I solve the problem

below is my code.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QObject>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QDateTime>

QSerialPort serial;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    mSerialport{new QSerialPort}
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(this->mSerialport,SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this,SLOT(readSerialData()));
    connect(ui->pushButton_send,
            &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){
        sendMsg(ui->textEdit->toPlainText());

    });

}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete mSerialport;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_connect_clicked()
{
    mSerialport->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    mSerialport->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    mSerialport->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    mSerialport->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    mSerialport->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    mSerialport->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    if (mSerialport->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    { QMessageBox::information(this,tr("connect"),
                               "serialcommunication start");
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("fail"),
                                 mSerialport->errorString());
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_disconnect_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("disconnect"),
                             "serial communication end");
    mSerialport->close();
}

void MainWindow::sendMsg(const QString &msg)
{
    QString str = msg;
    str.append("\n");
    this->mSerialport->write(str.toLatin1());

    ui->comLog->insertPlainText(QDateTime::currentDateTime().
                                toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " [send] " + msg + "\n");
}

void MainWindow::recvMsg(){
    QByteArray msg = this->mSerialport->readAll();
    ui->comLog->insertPlainText(QDateTime::currentDateTime().
                                toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + " [recieve] " + msg.toHex().
                                data() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Reading from the device? Using QTimer? Displaying the data? Please avoid including unnecessary information. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-can-example.html).

To store data in log file, you can write data like this.

```
QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
QFile file("log.csv");
file.open(QIODevice::Append);
file.write(data);
file.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I add the code 
//void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
    QFile file("log.csv");
    file.open(QIODevice::Append);
    file.write(data);
    file.close();
} //
 and excute but nothing happened and can't find log.csv . Instead of using upper code , what to do to solve the problem ? shoud i use can bus?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your reply . I write the code as you know me . but qt inform QIODevice:: write() is right. What should be written in parentheses ?

Comment: @kararara Excuse me,  Try with `file.open(QIODevice::Append|QIODevice::WriteOnly);` or `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);`

Comment: @eyllanesc there is no error thank you . but nothing changed before and after adding this code ..I do not seem to have any effect..

Comment: change `log.csv` to full path of `log.csv`

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm sorry, is that where I specify the location of this file after I create the log.csv file separately? I want to have serial communication so that when the device's data is stored in csv format it will be displayed on my ui.